# How to calculate how much wight a motor can lift?

Tags: motor, calculator

I know it might be a naive question but am not really an electrical or a mechanical engineer, but am in a situation here and I need some help. 
I work in motorized rolling doors and I need to know how to chose the right motor for the door I have. Basically **I want to calculate how much a motor can lift**,
maybe a general rule of thumb on how does it work.

So the information I have is Torque (Nm), hollow Shaft diameter (mm), voltage (V)
output speed (RPM), and motor output (kW).

And as an example of this is that i have an industral motor with

- **Torque** = 450 Nm,
- **Hollow Shaft** = 40 mm,
- **Voltage** = 230/400 V,
- **Output Speed** = 14 RMP
- **Motor output** = 1,5 kW

Answer (score 0):

Torque and Radius of the shaft are the necessary specs that you need for a first approach of the calculation.

The force at the radius of the hollow shaft can by calculated as

F = M / r = 450 Nm / 0,02 m = 22,5 kN

Depending on which planet you want to use the device, you can calculate the mass that you can lift against gravitational force. For earth it can be calculated as follows:

m = F / g = 22,5 kN / 9,81 m/s^2 = 2293,58 kg.